# How to use a UINavigationController on my second ViewController IOS XCODE 4.5

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am just slowly finding my feet with ios.  I've started a single view app with 2 ViewControllers.  My first VC is a splash screen with an expanded button filling the whole screen so I can use its method to transfer me to my second VC.  On my second VC, I want to embed a UItableView within a UINavigationController.  I know how to do this if I was starting with the first VC, by creating a new instance of the UINavigationController within the appDelegate, etc.  But I can't get my head around how to embed a UItableView  within  a UINavigationController within the second VC (ViewController).

Any help will be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a new navigation controller? You should use the same navigation controller to push the second VC.

In FirstViewController.m

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not implemented a navigation controller yet.  My first screen is literally a full screen image with "tap the screen to continue" round rect button that fills the screen.  I wanted to have a navigation controller from the second VC with an embedded table view so I can select rows that will take me to a third VC.

I would like a navigation controller so I can have the upper blue title bar with the back button.

The code I have so far to go from one VC to the other is:

```
ViewControllerSecond *view2 = [[ViewControllerSecond alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerSecond" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:view2 animated:YES completion:nil];
```